# How to remove text input when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function below when when an upload has been completed, it will store the name of the file in a string and it's id in a text input. Now at bottom of function, if the user clicks on the `deletevideofile` button, then it is able to remove the file name which is fine but my question is how can I remove the text input? I can't seem to get the text input to be removed.

Below is code:

```
function stopVideoUpload(success, videoID, videofilename){

      var result = '';
      videocounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
          $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<input type="text" name="vidid" value="' + videoID + '" />');
          $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefilevideo" video_file_name="' + videofilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');      }

  var _videocounter = videocounter;

$('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).find(".deletefilevideo").on("click", function(event) {
    var video_file_name = $(this).attr('video_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deletevideo.php?videofilename=" + video_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".videomsg" + _videocounter).html(data);
    });

    $(this).parent().remove();
});


      return true;   
}
```

Comment: @OneTrickPony No I tried this before but it doesn't remove the text input

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<input type="text" name="vidid" value="' + videoID + '" id="'+  videofilename +'" />');
          $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefilevideo" video_file_name="' + videofilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>');      }

var video_file_name = $(this).attr('video_file_name');
$('#'+video_file_name).remove();
```

Replace this code in your code and try to check... are you getting desired putput

Comment: Ok there is an issue with this. Lets say I upload 2 files so that I have a text input and file name for file 1 and text input and file name for file 2, then if I click on the remove button for file 2, it removes the text input in both files, when really it should only do it for file 2 only

Comment: It doesn't remove text input and file name when trying your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('input[name="vidid"]').val('').remove();
```

Comment: This does not remove anything when I tried it. The text input remoanins but so does the file name

Comment: Sorry, I should of seen the missing bracket. Anyway I texted this and even though i removes the text input, it now does not remove the filename

Comment: Amm...! Actually That should be `.val('')` instead of `.text('')` just updated plz you can try that one.

Comment: Tried it, same problem, file name not removed

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="vidid"]').remove();
```

Give this is a try:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('input[name="vidid"]').andSelf().remove();
```

For jQuery 1.8+ use [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead of [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

Comment: Ok there is an issue with this. Lets say I upload 2 files so that I have a text input and file name for file 1 and text input and file name for file 2, then if I click on the remove button for file 2, it removes the text input in both files, when really it should only do it for file 2 only

Comment: @user1964964 In that case you need to traverse the dom to get the correct element, it looks like Jai has it correct now that he's edited his answer

Comment: Please look at my latest comment under jai's answer

Comment: Just tried your edit, when I click `Remove` button for file 2, it removes text input and filename for file 2 which is fine but it also removes text input in file 1 which is incorrect